# Team Foundation Server 2012 Sample documents and Templates

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

As far as I understand Sample Documents and Templates for TFS are becoming available on a Team Site when you install SharePoint for TFS.. yes or no?

If so, is there a way to extract these documents from TFS without installing SharePoint site? I need these templates but am not willing to install and configure SharePoint at this time (waiting for SharePoint 2013).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 11.0\Tools\Deploy\ProcessTemplateManagerFiles\1033\MsfAgile\Template.zip\Windows SharePoint Services\Samples and Templates